# Generating constrained DISTINCT elements with SQL RAND()

Tags: mysql, sql, random, unique, distinct

I have a SQL (MySQL SQL) statement, something like the following, to grab 10 records from table `bar`:

```
SET @foo:=1;
SELECT DISTINCT
    @start:=ROUND(RAND()*100),
    @start+ROUND(RAND()*100)+1,
    CONCAT("id-",@foo:=@foo+1)
FROM
    bar
LIMIT 10
```

It generates unique elements like:

```
...
14   72   id-2
...
9    10   id-8
...
```

So far, so good. But what I would really like to do is use the `DISTINCT` keyword in a way such that duplicates do not get added, *based on the uniqueness of the first or first-and-second column values only*.

For example, at present, all 10 records are unique because the `id-n` element is always different for each record. So this is possible:

```
...
9    10   id-4
...
9    10   id-8
...
```

What I would like to do is keep the second `9  10  id-8` element from being in the result set (or, alternatively, `9  10  id-4` — I don't care which near-duplicates are left out). Is there a way to constrain the `DISTINCT` to the first or first-and-second columns?

I know I could leave out the `id-n` value from the SQL statement, and then post-process the results with downstream scripts that add that back in. However, out of curiosity, I'd like to find a solution contained within a SQL query. Thanks!

Comment: I tried `GROUP BY @start, @stop` (using your previous version where they were separate variables), which seems to be a step closer, but has really bizarre results.  Sometimes there are duplicates, and it doesn't always actually return 10 rows... go figure, the grouping functionality must be streamed so it doesn't handle random values very well.

Comment: I tried `GROUP BY @start` and my `mysql` session froze.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not 100% sure this is what you're trying to do, but it seems you could put the results of your query in a subquery, then use `MAX` to get the last record.

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT rand1col, rand2col, CONCAT("id-",Max(fooidcol)) as col3
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        @start:=ROUND(RAND()*100) as rand1col,
        @start+ROUND(RAND()*100)+1 as rand2col, 
        @foo:=@foo+1  as fooidcol
    FROM bar
) t
GROUP BY rand1col, rand2col
LIMIT 10
```

The problem with testing this is `RAND()` won't return me what I need for testing, so I created this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c1ea/2) with actual columns that try to do just that, but it appears to work with the above query as well.

And here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c1ea/4) with the above query -- works some of the time, just keep refreshing.

Comment: In theory, this should work, but the `GROUP BY ...` statement seems to cause my `mysql` session to hang. Not sure why.

Comment: Hmmmm, runs fine locally and on SQL Fiddle for me.  Maybe some configuration or something deeper.  How many records are in your table?  Perhaps a memory issue or something.  I've only tested with sample data.  Can you recreate the SQL Fiddle locally?  Good luck.

Comment: Another thought, if your table has lots of records, you could add another Limit clause in your subquery so rand won't be called so much.  Maybe limit to 100 so you know you'll still get 10.

Comment: You can remove the `DISTINCT` from the internal query. It's redundant anyway.